# pause ssis package

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

here is the scenario,

I got transaction history from another source (not my company) on CSV files. 
I import them using SSIS package and check row by row if the transaction is already on my system. 
After that, I need to check the amount of new items if consist on normal numbers, eg 500 items every week. 
If number is above that I need to check because maybe the source file didn´t came correctly (wrong colums order for example, extra space, etc), so no insert is done to my database.
If numbers is OK, then I need to add those items to my table on my database.

Up to now, I manage the package to insert new ones to a temporary table, then I manually check the rowcount and data itself if news are ok.

After that I do a manual query to insert from that temporary table to the final one.

I would like to know if I can do those extra steps directly on the main SSIS, like usinv a grid view to view the new items while the process is paused, and after I close the view, it continue the process inserting the new items.

Comment: You'll always be running the package through BIDS, no automated runs for your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do all of your steps in SSIS.  After you insert the records into the temp table;

- create an execute sql task to select the number of rows to insert and record the result into a variable
- check the variable number is within your acceptable range and use the workflow constraint to stop the package if the number is unacceptable
- if the number of rows are acceptable, create a data flow task to insert records from your temp table into the true target table